# Trapping bad enum

Tags: powershell, exception, enums

I am trying to use an enum in a PowerShell class constructor, where the enum is referenced with a variable in the call. That variable could be populated with something that doesn't resolve correctly, and of course I want to error trap that. Given this code

```
Enum pxPathType {
  FileSystem_Folder = 0
  FileSystem_File   = 1
  Registry_Key      = 2
  Registry_Property = 3
}

class PxPath {
    # Constructor
    PxPath ([string]$path, [pxPathType]$pathType) {
    }
}

$pathType = 'FileSystem_Folders'
$testPath = [PxPath]::New("C:\", [pxPathType]::$pathType)
```

I will get a very generic Method exception. Is it possible to somehow throw my own exception when I don't pass a valid enum? Or is the "correct" way to do this to validate the enum in advance with something like 
`if ([enum]::IsDefined(([pxPathType]), $pathType)) {`

I don't much like that option because there could be scopes of places where I would need an instance of the PxPath class, and so there will be ;lots of duplication of the validation. I would rather make the class self contained and throw an exception. I think. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement-terminating error (wrapping a `MethodException`) you get by default is a bit clumsy, but it does contain the relevant information:

```
MethodException: Cannot convert argument "pathType", with value: "", for ".ctor" to type "pxPathType": 
"Cannot convert null to type "pxPathType" due to enumeration values that are not valid.
Specify one of the following enumeration values and try again.
The possible enumeration values are "FileSystem_Folder,FileSystem_File,Registry_Key,Registry_Property"."
```

The only way to provide a custom error message without duplication is to define your constructor with a `[string]`-typed parameter instead, and perform your own validation inside it:

```
Enum pxPathType {
  FileSystem_Folder = 0
  FileSystem_File   = 1
  Registry_Key      = 2
  Registry_Property = 3
}

class PxPath {
  # Constructor
  # NOTE:  $pathType is now defined as [string]
  PxPath ([string]$path, [string]$pathType) {
    # Try to convert to the enum type, and provide a custom
    # error message if that fails.
    $pathTypeEnum = 
      try { [pxPathType] $pathType } 
      catch { Throw "Not a valid path type: $pathType" }
  }
}

$pathType = 'FileSystem_Folders'
$testPath = [PxPath]::New("C:\", 'NotValid')
```